# Why won't my Flutter app install on my iPhone XR?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a Flutter app which I have provisioned with an Adhoc certificate so I can try it on real devices. I have tried sending it to my iPhone XR via Itunes and with Diawi: https://i.diawi.com/Cx6r8U. When I install it, it shows up on the screen with its logo, however, when tapping it just says "Unable to install, please try again later".
What am I doing wrong and how can I help it?

[Here is an image to show the error I receive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdDMj.png)

Comment: If this is for test purpose have you checked if the udid is registered on apple devices section.

Comment: why don't you use TestFlight or Firebase Distribution? Those will have the correct certificates for you to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your phone's UDID.

[image]

2. Enter [Apple Developer Page](https://developer.apple.com/account/#!/welcome)
3. Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page.

[image]

4. Click 'Devices' on tab.
5. Click add button.

[image]

6. Then enter details.

[image]

7. Don't use this again, use TestFlight it is waaayy more easier.

Comment: thanks a lot, this ios environment is extremely confusing. I'll look into testflight